# Gradle sync failed: Process 'command '..android-studio/jre/bin/java''

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have downloaded [android studio 2.2.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) for linux.

When i create new project it will give error like:

```
Gradle 'myapplication' project refresh failed
Error:Process 'command '/home/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I have already try with oracle jdk 8 & open jdk 8 both but still facing the same issue.

Comment: have you add PATH for your installed Java?

Comment: You tried the JDK how exactly? Your error clearly says JRE

Answer (score 0):

**Note: first you have to setup the android studio correctly**

then you may not installed properly Oracle Java SDK 8 follow the steps in the below link  http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

add this in your gradle file, for me its fixed.

```
defaultConfig {

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i had followed the same steps from the same link.

Comment: fine, is your studio setup was ok

Comment: add this in your gradle file try and let me know defaultConfig {

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}

Comment: That's not the only step to enabling multidex

Answer (score 0):

tldr;

- click file/project structure
- uncheck "use embedded jdk"
- enter path to oracle jdk 8, ie /usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_152

I bumped into this while trying resolve my noob issues with android studio. Yes, I have oracle java jdk 8 installed and JAVA_HOME is pointing to it. You'd think the java gods would be happy.

But no, gradle defaults to the jre that is embedded into android studio. Why? idk & idc if it *works*. But it doesn't. So follow the steps above. If you are a noob like me, then prepare to be bored to death as stuff needs to be downloaded, adk, avd, & etc. You can't go grab coffee because you can't cue all the downloads. Yuck.

Comment: Gradle doesn't default to the embedded JRE, it has its own properties. All of Studio runs from the JRE.  The grade wrapper is executed within it's JVM, but you're welcome to use a separate Gradle installation

Comment: What are you basing your statement, "All of Studio runs from the JRE"? The error message clearly shows gradle is running 'android-studio/jre/bin/java'. Android Studio runs on what JAVA_HOME is set to. If I set it to openjdk8, I see messages suggesting oracle jdk. When I set JAVA_HOME to oracle jdk, no messages pop up.

Comment: A JDK contains a JRE and other things

Comment: Ok... and apparently Android Studio also "contains a JRE and other things."

Comment: Yes, it's a Jetbrains based IDE, which requires Java to run. Does not need to include a JRE, but that list of other things includes Maven, for example